# Applescript in Objective C project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to run this shell script command through applescript on my mac application. It works fine in the applescript editor but when I run it in xcode as shown below, it does not work. Am I doing it wrong?

```
NSString *asString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"property MACaddr : \"gg:gg:gg:gg:gg:gg\"\n property WAN_IP_address : \"255.255.255.255\"\n property port_number : \"9\"\n "
                    "on run\n set command to \"/usr/bin/php -r \" & quoted form of (\"$mac = \" & quoted form of MACaddr & \"; $porttemp = \" & quoted form of port_number & \";$ip = \" & quoted form of WAN_IP_address & \"; \" & \"" 
                                        "$mac_bytes = explode(\\\":\\\", $mac); "
                                          " $mac_addr = \\\"\\\"; "
                                          " for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) "
                                          " $mac_addr .= chr(hexdec($mac_bytes[$i]));" 
                                          " $packet = \\\"\\\"; "
                                          " for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++)   "
                                          " $packet .= chr(255); "
                                           "for ($i=0; $i<16; $i++)  "
                                           "$packet .= $mac_addr;" 
                                          " $port = $porttemp; "
                                           "$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);" 
                                           "socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, TRUE);" 
                                           "socket_sendto($sock, $packet, strlen($packet), 0, $ip, $port);" 
                                           "socket_close($sock);\") "
                                           "do shell script command \n"
                                            "end run"   ];
NSLog(@"the applescript %@", asString);
NSAppleScript *asScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:asString];
[asScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
[asString release];
[asScript release];
```

Here is the exact applescript that runs fine in my Applescript editor. I have edited the above part with the correct backslashes and all and its the same as my applescirpt which works. However, it still does not work in xcode and the magic packet is not being sent. (using wireshark to monitor this.) any ideas whats wrong? I even added the on run part.

```
property MACaddr : "gg:gg:gg:g4:g5:gg"
property WAN_IP_address : "255.255.255.255"
property port_number : "9"

on run
    set command to "/usr/bin/php -r " & quoted form of ("$mac = " & quoted form of     MACaddr & "; $porttemp = " & quoted form of port_number & ";$ip = " & quoted form of WAN_IP_address & "; " & " 


$mac_bytes = explode(\":\", $mac); 
$mac_addr = \"\"; 
for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) 
$mac_addr .= chr(hexdec($mac_bytes[$i])); 
$packet = \"\"; 
for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++)  /*6x 0xFF*/ 
$packet .= chr(255); 
for ($i=0; $i<16; $i++) /*16x MAC address*/ 
$packet .= $mac_addr; 

$port = $porttemp; 
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP); 
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, TRUE); 
socket_sendto($sock, $packet, strlen($packet), 0, $ip, $port); 
socket_close($sock); 
")
    do shell script command
end run
```

anyways, I have got it working FINALLY. no idea what exactly it was but here is the code for someone who wants to run a php script for WOL(wake on lan) magic packet through PHP as a shell script by applescript in a objective c environment. yup. here is the editied and working one:

```
NSString *asString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"property MACaddr : \"gg:gg:gg:gg:gg:gg\"\n property WAN_IP_address : \"255.255.255.255\"\n property port_number : \"9\"\n "
                    "on run\n set command to \"/usr/bin/php -r \" & quoted form of (\"$mac = \" & quoted form of MACaddr & \"; $porttemp = \" & quoted form of port_number & \";$ip = \" & quoted form of WAN_IP_address & \"; \" & \"\n" 
                                        "$mac_bytes = explode(\\\":\\\", $mac);\n "
                                          " $mac_addr = \\\"\\\";\n "
                                          " for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) "
                                          " $mac_addr .= chr(hexdec($mac_bytes[$i]));\n" 
                                          " $packet = \\\"\\\";\n "
                                          " for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++)\n     "
                                          " $packet .= chr(255);\n "
                                           "for ($i=0; $i<16; $i++)\n    "
                                           "$packet .= $mac_addr;\n" 
                                          " $port = $porttemp;\n "
                                           "$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);\n" 
                                           "socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, TRUE);\n" 
                                           "socket_sendto($sock, $packet, strlen($packet), 0, $ip, $port);\n" 
                                           "socket_close($sock);\")\n "
                                           "do shell script command \n"
                                            "end run"   ];
NSLog(@"the applescript %@", asString);
NSString *script2 = [asString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"gg:gg:gg:gg:gg:gg" withString:AirportMAC];
NSAppleScript *asScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script2];
[asScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
[asString release];
[asScript release];
```

Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: It looks like you have several layers of code there and that the various strings need to be double-escaped sometimes. i.e. `"$packet = \"\";"` looks like a php piece so it might need to be `"$packet = \\\"\\\";"`

Comment: "It does not work"- what happens, is there an error?

Comment: @epatel you are right, it was an issue for the slashes.However even after doing that, the script does not work... I have it in NSLog as the exact same thing I typed in Applescript Editor and it works fine in the editor.. Just when I run my application in xcode the packet is not sent.

Comment: @Archio It does not give an error. but the packet is not sent. I am using wireshark to capture the packet and its not being sent. yeah. any ideas? Ill post the exact applescript in my question.

Comment: Question: Why are you using AppleScript to run a command line?  You could do it directly from C by just using NSTask or even just the C system() routine...

Comment: I thought that would be the best way as I already had it working in the applescript editor. Will look into NSTask. But if I use NSTask or the C Systerm routine will the php part work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely an issue with the backslashed characters.  NSLog your asString variable and try running that printed code in the editor and you'll see the error.

Where you have quotes within the string, you'll need triple backslashes!

```
"$mac_bytes = explode(\":\", $mac); "
```

should be

```
"$mac_bytes = explode(\\\":\\\", $mac); "
```

and in other places as well.

Comment: Yup the backslashes was the issue and ive Nslogged it to the same script that runs in my applescript editor but not here in xcode. the magic packet is not being sent. yeah. Ill paste the exact applescript above.

Answer (score 1):

Never do this:

```
NSLog([asScript stringValue]);
```

Always do this:

```
NSLog("%@",[asScript stringValue]);
```

Passing unknown format strings to NSLog() is a quick path to the crash bin.

Comment: Which part is this in reference to?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. I don't mean to be harsh, it's just the truth.